# ListView getChildCount not returning correct value when it has children with small height

Tags: android, android-listview

So i'm trying to hack away an issue I'm having. To reach my goal of not having views i set the height of the view, in the adapter, to 5 pixel. To make sure they're being drawn i also set the background color to a whole different one.

When calling getChildCount in the custom listView It doesn't seem to count the smaller views even though they are clearly visible and on the screen.

I'm wondering if the listview is miscalculating the number of views in the screen due to the difference in height and if so how should i fix it.

Comment: That wouldn't work since I'm working on a list view and not a viewpager

Comment: Ah, good point. Sorry, shouldn't read SE late at night!

Comment: Don't worry I found out the problem 5 minutes ago while I was in the bath. I need to set view type count accordingly or the list view won't calculate right.